# Any free Tools to display more than 5000 geography objects in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database, visualisation, road

SQL Server 2008 and up allow you to create a spatial index. If you select records that include a geography or geometry object, a spatial data tab appears that can display up to 5000 points or lines or other shapes. You can select a label column, pan, and zoom. I am trying to debug a road network dataset that has disconnected islands of roads and need to be able to display all the line segments for a given state and label the disconnected ones so I can see where the missing roads are. That means I need to **display more than 5000 objects**.

Are there any free tools that can do this, including the labeling (color labels would be ok if text labels are not supported)? I have about 250,000 line segments, but anything that can display 50,000 would be okay for my work. A **plugin for SSMS** would be best, but an external tool would work, too. If there is a **C# .NET library**, I could use that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [SharpGIS SqlSpatial Query Tool](http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SqlSpatial-Query-Tool).

Comment: It does not appear to support zoom, but you can pan, can view attributes by hovering over a line, and define a line or fill color, so this will work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS will read SQL Server spatial data - you should be able to connect to your database, see your tables, and add them to the map canvas and zoom down however you like.

Your database interaction will be limited to what you can do in the layer properties dialogue box.